# iOS intercept notifications (notification listener)

Tags: ios, notifications, listener

Is there any way to read iOS notifications (like Android's `NotificationListener`)? I just need to know which app sent a notification.

Comment: Thankfully iOS doesn't allow this.

Answer (score 0):

No, iOS environment is totally different in this respect. It won't allow any application to read any info related to other applications. That's what makes **iOS system so secure**.

For the same reason(security purpose), you don't have access over notification area of iOS. So to put the answer in a single word it's "**NO**"

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I thought this would be possible since some smartwaches apps are able to do just that. How do they do it then?

Comment: No, there might misconception with some other thing. Few people might mimic something. Can you please specify exactly what they are doing?

Comment: I am working on an app to show the app icon of the latest notification. I wold like to get the notifications from the Notification Center. So I just need the app which sent the notification, I don't need to know what the notification says.

Comment: Even that also it won't allow @RegorJogal. To give more info about how much apple made it's rules, recently in iOS 10 they came up with something called whitelisting of URLSchemes to stop users from knowing whether app is installed or not that's it. It's just an example I'm telling.

Comment: @RegorJogal I don't mean to disappoint you about this but why I'm coming up with bullet answer NO because I don't want you to waste your time to find out it's not possible.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer. But how does for example the android wear app do that?

Comment: Yes I agree that android is giving this control to developer to find out

Comment: In fact, it's giving more control to know what's the notification content also.

Comment: I mean the android wear app on iOS does exactly this. How do they do it?

Comment: @RegorJogal Please accept this answer, if you found it useful. So that it will be helpful others as well